# How can I load a Google Play app in the Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play, emulation

I need to load an app into my AVD, but Google Play isn't included in the built-in system images. What do I do to get the app so I can install it?

Comment: Are you referring to Google Play Services?

Comment: @RogueBaneling - No, I mean how do I download an apk from Google Play so I can load it into the emulator?

Answer (score 17):

Please note that this package will only work for Android 4.3.

Let’s begin by launching the SDK manager. We’ll first need to ensure that Android 4.3 (API 18) is installed.

```
[pyoor@localhost tools]$ ./android sdk
```

If not, check the top level element, “Android 4.3 (API 18)”, click “Install 6 Packages”, and accept the license agreement.

Once installed, close the SDK manager and launch the AVD manager. Here we’ll need to create a new AVD which utilizes the Android 4.3 platform and has snapshots enabled so that any changes we make are persistent.

```
[pyoor@localhost tools]$ ./android avd
```

Next we need to pull down the appropriate Google Apps package. Using Android 4.3 (API 18) we must use the “20130813” package.

https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23060877490000124

Once downloaded, extract the archive. In order to install Google Play, we’ll need to push the following 3 APKs to our AVD (located in ./system/app/):

```
GoogleServicesFramework.apk
GoogleLoginService.apk
Phonesky.apk
```

However, before we do, we need to make some minor modifications to our AVD. Let’s launch the newly created AVD using the following command. Note that we’ve specified a partition size of 512MB. This is to ensure that our AVD has enough capacity to install the Google Play Store and its dependencies.

```
[pyoor@localhost tools]$ ./emulator -avd Test -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim
```

This may take several minutes the first time as the AVD is created. Once started we need to remount the AVD’s partition and modify the permissions of “/system/app/” as this is where our packages will be installed to.

```
[pyoor@localhost platform-tools]$ ./adb remount
[pyoor@localhost platform-tools]$ ./adb shell chmod 777 /system/app
```

And finally, we can push these APKs to our AVD:

```
[pyoor@localhost platform-tools]$ ./adb push ~/system/app/GoogleServicesFramework.apk /system/app/
[pyoor@localhost platform-tools]$ ./adb push ~/system/app/GoogleLoginService.apk /system/app/
[pyoor@localhost platform-tools]$ ./adb push ~/system/app/Phonesky.apk /system/app/
```

Now if your emulator is as slow as mine it may take a few minutes for the package to be installed. You’ll know if the installation hasn’t yet completed if the launcher process repeatedly crashes on you ;)

After a few minutes, we should see the Google Play package appear within the menu launcher. After associating a Google account with this AVD we now have a fully working version of Google Play running under your emulator.

Please refer to this link since `goo.im` is no longer maintened: http://www.flinkd.org/2013/12/installing-google-play-on-the-android-emulator-api-18/

That should do the work.

Comment: @bummi now it's complete.

Comment: goo.im is shutdown, any other alternative links ?

Comment: @poring91 you can try Android File Host. Check the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Any reason to not use Genymotion instead of the official Android emulator?

Genymotion has virtual devices with Google Apps preinstalled. Not all of them, but a few let you load the Play Store app and download apps as if it were a real device.

[image]

Comment: Just downloaded Genymotion and currently there are no images with google apps preinstalled

Comment: @Poma you haven't found even one image saying "with Google Apps"? My Genymotion installation still has, perhaps its versions is rather old? Haven't upgraded it lately

Comment: They removed ARM Translator and Google apps from new versions but it is possible to reinstall them manually

Comment: Genymotion is free only for personal use. For business, it costs 24.99 $/ mont per user.

Comment: @caBBAlainB here you have instructions: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-install-google-play-services-on-android-emulator-genymotion/

Answer (score 0):

ou have to download 1.ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip and 2.gapps-jb-20121212.signed.zip. 1st you have to drag the ARM-Translation and a/c to instruction you will go. 2nd step you have to drag the gapps-jb-20121212 then a/c to instruction you will go then u see in your Genymotion emulator has playstore or some google apps .... i think i will help to you....

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and I managed to find a relatively simple method to get the Play Store on an emulated Android instance.

As mentioned, [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) has a decent emulated Android offering. There is also [Xamarin Android Player](https://xamarin.com/android-player) which currently has a preview release available for download.

When you have one of those available you'll need to grab a signed gapps package for use with the version of Android the emulator is running. Team Android has downloads for popular versions [here](http://www.teamandroid.com/gapps/).

When you have the emulator running and the gapps file downloaded then you can simply drag and drop the zip file into the emulator and it will determine it's a signed package that can be installed. Install the package, restart and you'll have the Play store available.

[Related Xamarin how-to guide](https://university.xamarin.com/resources/how-to-install-google-play-on-android-emulator)

Answer (score -1):

1st you have to download genymotion library anfter that whatever in your pc i.e. Eclipse or android studio you have to put the plugins and take genymotion emulator.
After this you have to download two zip file 1.gapps-jb-20121212-signed
2.Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1
1st you have to drag ARM Translation on genymotion
2nly you have to drag gapps-jb-20121212 and a/c to dailog you read the message and clicked when it successful install then in genymotion google play store app will be present.